# What is the maximum length of URL in browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, url, firefox, maxlength

I'm looking for an offical number on the maximum characters that can be passed via URL string.

Is it different for each browser? If so I'm looking for IE6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url/417184#417184

Answer (score 3):

It is different for each browser. For IE the querystring length max is ~2048 characters. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427
(Not sure if this is still the case for IE9 but should be relavent for IE6-IE8)

Comment: It still ~2048 in IE9, I just tested

Answer (score 0):

2006-10-13: Although the specification of the HTTP protocol does not specify any maximum length, practical limits are imposed by web browser and server software.
Microsoft Internet Explorer (Browser)

Microsoft states that the maximum length of a URL in Internet Explorer is 2,083 characters, with no more than 2,048 characters in the path portion of the URL. In my tests, attempts to use URLs longer than this produced a clear error message in Internet Explorer.
Firefox (Browser)

After 65,536 characters, the location bar no longer displays the URL in Windows Firefox 1.5.x. However, longer URLs will work. I stopped testing after 100,000 characters.
Safari (Browser)

At least 80,000 characters will work. I stopped testing after 80,000 characters.
Opera (Browser)

At least 190,000 characters will work. I stopped testing after 190,000 characters. Opera 9 for Windows continued to display a fully editable, copyable and pasteable URL in the location bar even at 190,000 characters.

For more research see this link http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html